# Changing the chrome of a Windows 10 Universal XAML app

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I would like to modify the design of the chrome and top menu panel of my app where the close and minify icons are.

How do I do this and in what XAML file? Should it be done in App.xaml, or in my main page's xaml file? I can find instructions on how to do this in a WPF app, but the concepts don't seem to carry over to Univeral App XAML.

Comment: Are you asking about the style of the command/app bar? Or the actual bar where the "close app" button is located when working on a desktop?

Comment: The "close app" button on desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can change some settings from the chrome bar in the [uwp](/questions/tagged/uwp), but not fully customize it **by default**.

The starting point for doing so would be the [ApplicationView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.aspx)'s [TitleBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationviewtitlebar.aspx) property.

This allows you to change the colors of the buttons and the bar itself:

```
var titleBar = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;
if (titleBar != null)
{
    titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = Colors.DarkBlue;
    titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.White;
    titleBar.BackgroundColor = Colors.Blue;
    titleBar.ForegroundColor = Colors.White;
}
```

It is worth mentioning that when running the application on a PC, the control is called **TitleBar** but on a mobile device, it is called **StatusBar**. Full example for handling both devices can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gianlucb/archive/2015/10/08/uwp-windows-10-app-titlebar-and-status-bar-customization.aspx).

If you need more personalization options, creating your own `TitleBar` component should be possible, look for the `ExtendViewIntoTitleBar` property of the `CoreApplicationViewTitleBar` object.

More info can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplicationviewtitlebar.extendviewintotitlebar.aspx).

Comment: Just knowing that it's called TitleBar and StatusBar has helped. Found this useful artical as well: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/eternalcoding/2015/08/20/uwptake-the-control-of-your-title-bar/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a resource dictionary with the custom styles. You can import these themes via App.Xaml to apply it.

These links might be of help. If you have any specific questions feel free to ask.

[ResourceDictionary and XAML resource references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/mt187273.aspx)

[XAML theme resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/mt187274.aspx)